# Exported TeeChart to PDF shows error in Acrobat Reader after printing

Tags: wpf, vb.net, pdf, teechart

When exporting a TeeChart to a PDF I get an error after printing it with Acrobat Reader X.

**EDIT**: When using different fonts none of used fonts is found and all are replaced by a standard font.

Code

```
    chart.Export.Image.PDF.Height = Math.Round(chart.ActualHeight, 0)
    chart.Export.Image.PDF.Width = Math.Round(chart.ActualWidth, 0)
    chart.Export.Image.PDF.Save(filename)
```

btw. needed to round the hight/width as the exported PDF is broken sometimes when not doing so. Maybe because of the sometime many digits of ActualHeight values in WPF.

Sample file: [PDF](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1oGNV20z_u0LXl5cXJ4OUtiSXc/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**Error message from Acrobat Reader X**

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.

Open in GSView (or other PDF Viewers like SumatraPDF) throw no error, but GSView show alot of stuff in the messages.

**Messages from GSView**

```
GSview 5.0 2012-01-17
GPL Ghostscript 9.07 (2013-02-14)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Scanning PDF file
   **** Warning:  length of some xref entries is not equal to 20 bytes.
%GSVIEW_PDF_PAGES: 1 1
Displaying PDF page 1
%GSVIEW_PDF_PAGE: 1
%GSVIEW_PDF_MEDIA: [0 0 400 250]
%GSVIEW_PDF_ROTATE: 0
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
Scanning c:\psfonts for fonts... 0 files, 0 scanned, 0 new fonts.
Warning: EPS file must not use /setglobal
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/F0.
Can't find (or can't open) font file F0.
Querying operating system for font files...
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Courier for F0.
Loading NimbusMonL-Regu font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusMonL-Regu... 3168784 1826611 4629224 3331406 3 done.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
   **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: F0 Assuming it's a font name.
```

I changed all fonts from axis, legend, title... but error still appears. Looks like the font name is not written to the generated PDF.

Anything I can do about that? Looks not so good to get an error message each time you want to print an PDF from TeeChart.

Using TeeChart WPF (4.1.2012.1312), but made a test project with win forms and the same error shows.

Comment: Do you have an example PDF you can share?

Comment: Uploaded the file that creates the show errors [PDF](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1oGNV20z_u0LXl5cXJ4OUtiSXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I ran the file through callas pdfToolbox and looked at the actual PDF objects. I don't know how to fix your problem but the file you have is absolutely wrong. The page does in fact reference a font called "F0" (as indicated by Ghostscript) but the actual resource dict of the page doesn't contain ANY fonts. Are there any options to specify how fonts should be included when exporting? Exporting options?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing I'm know of or found. Thats why I tried to set the used fonts of everything to something different. But still getting the same results :/

Comment: @DavidSdot I could not reproduce the problem here using current TeeChart for .NET release (build ). Can you please send a simple example project we can run "as-is" to generate such wrong PDF? You can post your files at http://www.steema.net/upload/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet The link you provided won't work for me, so I uploaded the project to my [google drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1oGNV20z_u0a3dBS0w2ZnVvcU0/edit?usp=sharing). It's a win form project but it generates the same pdf as the wpf dll.

Comment: @DavidSdot Thanks for the example project. I can not reproduce the problem here with build 4.1.2013.05280 and Acrobat Reader XI. Can you please check if this build solves the problem for you. After printing the document I get this error message though: "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem."

Comment: @NarcísCalvet "An errror ... problem." thats exactly my problem, I'll try later with the latest TeeChart version.
Is it possible that you check the PDF you saved or send it to me so I can check it, if the font names are included?

Comment: @NarcísCalvet I used different fonts in the chart are those displayed correct in the PDF or not?
Mine (with 4.1.2012.1312) are all replaced by the same standard font.

Comment: @DavidSdot sure, PDF file I generated can be download [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/Chart1.pdf). The error message allows me viewing and printing the file correctly though.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet Thanks, just checked the file and it's the same problem as the one I made. The Font names are not included/embedded. The font for the bottom axis is a different than title's font, but the PDF uses the same font for all labels.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet, your file is just as broken. The page stream still references a font (/F0) but the page resource dict includes no font information at all.

Comment: @DavidSdot I see, font name is not preserved in the PDF export. I have added the issue (TF02016650) to the bug list to be fixed for future releases. Posted this as the answer to the question too.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet Thanks for looking into it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this error message after printing the PDF file:

*"An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem."*

The file prints correctly but the PDF file ignores font name settings so I have added the defect (TF02016650) to the bug list to be fixed.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as there seems to be no workaround for TeeChart 4.1.2013.05280 and earlier.

Comment: @DavidSdot I'm sorry but there's no workaround I can think of. The only solution I could think is non-TeeChart related. It would mean exporting the file to another image format and then convert it to PDF (might be done with a PDF virtual printer).

Comment: Problem is I need the generated Charts as PDFs and join them in a new PDF that is build with PDFSharp. An Image format as JPEG or PNG is not useable as the charts must look very good and needed to be zoomable within the PDF and PDFSharp can not sadly not handle other formats like SVG.

Comment: @DavidSdot yes, that would be a problem with raster image formats. What about using PostScript instead which is also a vector format?

Comment: Will have a look for it, but PDFSharp does not take to many image formats and I think Postscript is not one of them. Currently looking for something to handle that problem.

Comment: If the output to PostScript works correctly, you could do that and subsequently convert the PostScript to PDF. This would give you a correct PDF file to work with PDFSharp in the next step...